# Ensure CORS response header values are valid

Tags: express, socket.io, cors

I was building a chat webapp using react, socket-io, express, psql and redis. I am using cookie sessions to store user information and auto login for 7 days. In development everything was good. I handled the cors in development mode I am using helmet and cors and I configured the cors right way. The problem started after deployment there is an issue in the console area saying Ensure CORS response header values are valid. Now coming to the details. This is a demo of one of my fetch method in the client side

```
fetch(`https://mychat-server-sable.vercel.app/auth/register`, {
    method:"POST",
    credentials:"include",
    mode:"cors",
    headers:{
      "Content-Type":"application/json",
    },
    body:JSON.stringify(vals)
  }).catch(err => {
    return;
  }).then(res => {
    if(!res || !res.ok || res.status >= 400) {
      return;
    }
    return res.json()
  }).then(data => {
    if(!data) {
      return;
    }
    setUser({...data})
    if(data.status) {
      setError(data.status)
    }else if(data.loggedIn) {
      navigate("/home")
    }
})
```

And this is how I handled the socket configuration in the client side

```
import {io} from "socket.io-client";

const socket = new io(`https://mychat-server-sable.vercel.app`, {
    autoConnect:false,
    withCredentials:true,
})

export default socket;
```

This is how I handle the cors error in the server side

```
const corsConfig = {
  origin:"https://chat-pheonix.netlify.app",
  credentials: true,
};

const express = require("express");

const server = require("http").createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, { cors: corsConfig });

app.use(helmet());

app.use(cors(corsConfig));
```

In development everything was good then I deployed the client in netlify and the server in vercel. I created the psql and redis database in vercel and created the needed tables for the project. This is an image of my problem.

[image]

As you can see that it says I am missing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header from preflight requests and this is a picture of the preflight request and the actual request

[image]

As you can see that the preflight request is successful and it is coming back with the response header so there is no point of causing that issue. This is picture of the actual request

[image]

As you can see the status is 504 and sometimes it is also 500.

I tried chatgpt and she was suggesting this to put to send the headers

```
app.options("/auth/login", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://chat-pheonix.netlify.app");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.options("/auth/register", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://chat-pheonix.netlify.app");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

But the result remained still the same.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with CORS.  The application proxy isn't serving CORS-enabling headers on its error responses.  But, the root problem it something else.

Since you say you're getting a `500` sometimes and a `504` other times, I'd guess that your server is crashing with some error (when you get the `500`) and hasn't restarted yet or is otherwise not passing enough health checks when you get the `504`.

All you can do is check your application's error logs to see what's up.  The problem is server-side.

Comment: But in my code I use this get method -->
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json("Lol");
});
So, it should display the valid json but I get this weird symbols ��-��. Although in the vercel I see Lol message in the successful deployment image where it shows a glimpse of the page. And point to be noted that I am using expres.json() method to parse the json. So, there is no point showing those weird symbols. And no matter how much I try I cannot debug this error. I know it might be a silly reason but no error is silly until it is debugged. :(